# Including weather report in website using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to include the weather report at ftp://ftp.knmi.nl/pub_weerberichten/basisverwachting.xml to my website.

The specific element I want to include is located at:

```
report/data/location/block
```

where block contains:

```
<field_id>Verwachting</field_id>
```

How do I do this using simple XSL Transformations?

Update:

I have the following XSL Transformation however it has no results:

```
<xsl:variable name="weerknmi" select="document('ftp://ftp.knmi.nl/pub_weerberichten/basisverwachting.xml')/report/data/location"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$weerknmi/block[field_id = 'Verwachting']/field_content"/>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy transformation which you need just run to produce the wanted result. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
report/data/location/block[field_id='Verwachting']/field_content
```

**Here is a complete and really short XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select=
 "document('ftp://ftp.knmi.nl/pub_weerberichten/basisverwachting.xml')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc" mode="doc"/>
 </xsl:template>  

 <xsl:template match="/" mode="doc">
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "report/data/location/block[field_id='Verwachting']/field_content"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to any document (not used), the transformation dynamically obtains the XML document located ar ftp://ftp.knmi.nl/pub_weerberichten/basisverwachting.xml**, **processes it and the wanted result is produced**:

Vrij veel bewolking en vooral in het noorden af en toe regen of motregen. In het zuiden blijft het overwegend droog. De middagtemperatuur loopt uiteen van een graad of 14 in het Waddengebied tot 19 graden in het zuidoosten. De zuidwestelijke wind is matig tot vrij krachtig. Aan de kust is de wind krachtig of hard,  6 tot 7.

Komende nacht is er vrij veel bewolking met in het noorden en midden mogelijk nog lichte regen. De minimumtemperatuur ligt rond een graad of 11. De zuidwestelijke wind neemt af naar zwak tot matig, rond kracht 3. Aan de kust is de wind af en toe vrij krachtig, 5.

Morgen overdag breekt op steeds meer plaatsen de zon door en is het vrijwel overal droog. De middagtemperatuur loopt uiteen van een graad of 16 in het noordwestelijk kustgebied tot 23 graden in het zuidoosten. De zuidwestelijke wind trekt weer aan en wordt matig tot vrij krachtig, kracht 4 of 5, aan de kust en op het IJsselmeer krachtig tot hard, 6 of 7 Bft. â€™s Avonds neemt de wind af. (Bron: KNMI)

Comment: I tried using this XSL transformation on an empty XML file but the result is empty. There are no parse errors. I target Firefox 4.0.1. Are you sure the Xpath query is correct?

Answer (score 1):

A simple XPath expression will do this:

`report/data/location/block[field_id = 'Verwachting']/field_content`

If you want to use this in XSLT, you can just do:

`<xsl:value-of select="document('ftp://ftp.knmi.nl/pub_weerberichten/basisverwachting.xml')/report/data/location/block[field_id = 'Verwachting']/field_content" />`

I might have the syntax slightly wrong, I don't often use `document()` and I can't easily check it at the moment, but you get the idea.

Comment: removing the square bracked after field_content fixed the syntax errors, however the transformation has no result. I updated the question

Comment: Woops, that was definitely a typo! I've fixed it.